# Python List Comprehension Loop Over Multiple Collections

Tags: python-3.x

Say I'm trying to generate a list like this using a comprehension:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

I'm receiving an error "TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable" when trying to do:

```
mylist = [(letter,num) for letter in 'abcd' and num in range(1,4)]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
mylist = [letter for letter in zip('abcd' , range(1,5))]
```

**Or** If you want the length to be dynamic.

```
myString = "abcd"
lengthOfStr= len(myString )
mylist = [letter for letter in zip(myString , range(1,lengthOfStr))]
```

We here `zip` two `iterables` and zip itself return `tuple`.

Comment: The range should be from 1 to 5, because stop index should be one more than last index. `mylist = [letter for letter in zip('abcd' , range(1,5))]`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quite a few things actually.

- `range(1,4)` generates the following numbers : 1,2,3
- why do you think you should connect the lists using "`and`"?
- and finally, you are missing `zip`

Comment: To your question (second point), I was keying off of what was said here in this tutorial, which seemed to make sense given that you can chain conditionals in comprehensions: https://youtu.be/AhSvKGTh28Q?t=80